# Somehow COM object instance gets lost

Tags: delphi, com

I have a main app and a type library contains 2 COM objects, one is IFile, one is IFiles. IFiles creates IFile, and stores them in a TLIST, and has standard methods like Add, Remove etc. Both IFile and IFiles are TAutoObject.

"Add" method in IFiles is working fine, it simply creates IFile object [Code 1], and adds it to TList. Problem is IFile object instance gets lost in a very strange way. see [Code 2]

[Code 1]

```
function IFiles.Add(AFilename: String): IFile;
begin
  Result := CoIFile.Create;
  Result.Filename := AFilename;
  // ShowMessage(IntToStr(Result._AddRef));
  fFiles.Add(@Result);
end;
```

In the main app I have test code like this.
[Code 2]

```
var
  i: Integer;
  f: IFile;
  Files: IFiles;
begin
  Files := CoTIFile.Create;
  for i:= 1 to 4 do
  begin
    // Create a dummy file object
    f := Files.Add('Filename ' + IntToStr(i));
    f._AddRef; // Not sure if AddRef works like this
    // Prints out the last file
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Files.Files[i-1].Filename);
  end;

  for i:= 0 to Files.Count-1 do
  begin
    f := Files.Files[i];
    // F is nil at all time.
    if (f<>nil) then Memo1.Lines.Add(f.Filename); // ! No print out.
  end;  
end;
```

From the 2nd loop, even though fFiles.Count = 4, but all contents have lost. Do I need some extra treatment in IFile to handle AddRef and Release? or the way IFiles.Add method I wrote is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using TInterfaceList rather than TList to store the instances of IFile.  This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your original code was that you were adding an `IFile` *pointer* to the list, but when you read a value out of the list later, you assigned the pointer directly to another `IFile` variable. So you had was was essentially a `PIFile` value stored in an `IFile` variable. Delphi generally allows you to assign the untyped `Pointer` type to any pointer-like type, including interfaces.

To fix your original code, you would need to write the second look something like this:

```
var
  p: Pointer;

for i := 0 to Pred(Files.Count) do begin
  p := Files.Files[i];
  if not Assigned(p) then
    continue;
  f := IFile(p^);
  if not Assigned(f) then
    continue;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(f.Filename);
end;
```

You were right to call `f._AddRef` in your first loop. When `IFiles.Add` returns, the reference count on the result is `1` because the value stored in the loop is a pointer, not the actual reference. You need to increment the reference count because `f` is going to be re-used for other values. Since the reference you're manually counting is stored in the `FFiles` list, it would be better to call `_AddRef` inside `IFiles.Add` instead of waiting until it returns.

When you clear the list, or as you remove items from the list, you would need to call `_Release` on all the interface references.

But [Toby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728673/somehow-com-object-instance-gets-lost/728739#728739) gives the better idea: Use `TInterfaceList` to store a list of interfaces. `TList` simply isn't suited to the task by itself.

A final piece of advice: The "I" prefix on names is used to denote *interface* types. Interfaces don't have method implementations of their own. You've shown the implementation of `IFiles.Add`, so `IFiles` clearly isn't an interface type. It should be named `TFiles` instead, or maybe `TFileList`.

Answer (score 0):

The COM objects i automaticly released if there is no references to it.
In Code 1 the COM object gets released at the "end" statement.

I think you need to creat a wrapper object, and that wrapper object is what you add to files.

In sory i don't have the time to creat an example right now.